# Leuenberger's inequality

Tags: inequality, euclidean-geometry, triangles

Leuenberger's inequality states that the sum of the medians of a triangle is at most the sum of its exradii. I understand how to prove this when the triangle is acute. However, the proof I've seen in Bottema et. al., or even here: https://www.cut-the-knot.org/triangle/LeuenbergerInequality.shtml is wrong (look at it carefully, it doesn't work for an obtuse triangle since one of the cosines is negative, so $p_a+p_b+p_c$ is greater than $R+r$ in this case. In fact, if $C$ is the obtuse angle then $p_a+p_b-p_c=R+r$).
How to fix the proof for obtuse triangles? and, is there a simple unified proof for all triangles?

Comment: See my solution here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2078139

Comment: Thank you Michael, I'll look at it. Although I was precisely trying to avoid a brute force approach, thanks anyway.

Comment: I don't think you should close this topic. There should be a more elegant solution for the obtuse case.

Comment: Your question is a duplicate and we need to close it as a duplicate. If someone wants to post another solution so he can do it in the linked topic.